# Control D+ and D- USB lines using an arduino disconnect/connect

Tags: usb, electronics

I am using Arduino to remotely trigger a shutter action. All is well, until I hook up a USB cable on the 4 regular USB pins. This cable runs between a Sony camera and a printer. But I can not take an image when the D+ and D- are connected.

At this moment I have a manual switch in the usb cable. It works, but I would rather have Arduino kill the line, take the image and restore the line.

I understand I can use a relay, but is there another way?

Is a TRIAC an option? How would I need to hook up the components.

Comment: triac? that is for AC. I am not an expert., but you don't want any interference on the data lines so the control circuit mut be isolated from the data lines. so a relay I guess is the only good way.

Comment: It this USB connection you're talking about doing something like PictBridge?

Comment: I would say this is better suited for electrical stackexchange. It is more about the electrical part of the USB interface and not about Arduino. I think there you will get better answers.

Comment: I thought of the triac because of it's use in a solid state relay. USB data lines are bi-directional, that's why I thought about TRIACS. My safest bett will be a 2 channel relay I guess.